# How to get just one image path from multiple images paths in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am woring on multiple images upload in laravel 5.2 and i'm not using Intervention. I need just one image for thumbnail view and all the images after clicking the thumbnail for image gallery. I have been successfully uploading images but not been able to fetch into view.I have two tables posts and images.

---

posts table
| id | title description
 
images table
| id | p_id | path 
I have setup relationship like this.

```
// Post model
public function images()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Image','p_id');
}
//Image model
public function posts()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Post','p_id');
}
```

Comment: You can use `$post->images()->first()`;

Comment: Sorry that didnot do anything. Instead i did $post->images()->first ()['path']; and boom ! Thanks mate any way !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts=Post::with('images')->get();
```

then, this gives the first image path, you can use for thumbnail.

```
$posts[0]->images[0]->path;
```

and, this gives all the images path.

```
foreach($posts as $post)
{
   foreach($post->images as $image)
    {
       $image->path;
    }
}
```

Comment: $posts[0]->images[0]->path gave single image but all posts have same image.